# What's the meaning of flex in that case?

Tags: meaning

I just saw a comment from YouTube, but don't know what its meaning is.

After checking the dictionary, I couldn't find a matching meaning for the above sentence.

Who can give an explanation, Thanks.

> I just realized. He is not flexing on us, he is flexing on his ex wife.

From: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VX96I7PO8YU

Comment: At what time in the 10-minute video do the words occur?

Comment: it's not in the video, it's the first comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first still image (I didn't play the video) I guess it is given in the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Flex) as

> Showing off your valuables in a non-humble way.

You might like to bookmark this link to [OneLook](https://onelook.com/) so you can research your questions. I looked in Urban Dictionary first, as I guessed it was street talk but had not come across it before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems like matching the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Flex can be seen as a way to show off your values or strength in something. A common expression is " to flex one´s muscles". You flex your muscles to intimidate someone somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It's a metaphor transfered from *flexing one's muscles* to the general case of boasting and banter.